# IPC/RPC for communication between R and Python

Tags: python, r, python-2.7, ipc, rpc

### Summary

I'm looking for an IPC/RPC protocol which:

- Has libraries in both [R](http://www.r-project.org/) and [Python](https://www.python.org/) 2.7 which work on Windows
- Allows me to pass data and make calls between the two languages
- Does not embed one language inside the other (I want to use Python and R in my favourite IDEs, not embedding bits of R expression strings in Python code, vice/versa)
- Supports circular references
- Supports millisecond time data
- Fast and efficient when I need to pass large amounts of data

I have seen [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11716923/python-interface-for-r-programming-language), but unlike the OP for that question, I **do not** want to use R in a pythonic way. I want to use R in an R way in my RStudio IDE. And I want to use Python in a Pythonic way in a PyCharm IDE. I just want to occasionally pass data or make calls between the two languages, not to blend the languages into one.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

### Background

I use both Python and R interactively (by typing into the console of my favourite IDE: [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) and [RStudio](http://www.rstudio.com/) respectively). I often need to pass data and call functions between the two languages ad-hoc when doing exploratory data analysis. For instance, I may start with processing data in Python, but later stumble across a great machine learning library in R that I want to try out, vice/versa.

I've looked at Python libraries [PypeR](http://www.webarray.org/softwares/PypeR/) and [rpy2](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/) but both embed R within Python, so I lose the ability to use R interactively within RStudio. I have also looked at [RPython](http://rpython.r-forge.r-project.org/), but I use Windows and it does not work with Windows.

Additionally, I've looked at XML-RPC but some of my data has objects which contain circular references (e.g. a tree structure where child nodes have references to their parent). Problem is, Python's [xmlrpclib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xmlrpclib.html) does not support circular references, nor timestamps to millisecond precision which my data also contains.

Comment: Use pipe (which means it's not working on Windows) to read data from any other process