# How to predict a value with linear regression?

Tags: python, scipy, regression

I want to predict the behavior of my data in the future. The value of my data  x and y is about 1000 values. I want to predict the value y[1001].
This is my example.

```
from numpy.random import randn
from numpy.random import seed
from numpy import sqrt
import numpy
from numpy import sum as arraysum
from scipy.stats import linregress
from matplotlib import pyplot

seed(1)
x = 20 * randn(1000) + 100
print(numpy.size(x))
y = x + (10 * randn(1000) + 50)
print(numpy.size(y))
# fit linear regression model
b1, b0, r_value, p_value, std_err = linregress(x, y)
# make predictions
yhat = b0 + b1 * x
# define new input, expected value and prediction
x_in = x[1001]
y_out = y[1001]
yhat_out = yhat[1001]
# estimate stdev of yhat
sum_errs = arraysum((y - yhat)**2)
stdev = sqrt(1/(len(y)-2) * sum_errs)
# calculate prediction interval
interval = 1.96 * stdev
print('Prediction Interval: %.3f' % interval)
lower, upper = y_out - interval, y_out + interval
print('95%% likelihood that the true value is between %.3f and %.3f' % (lower, upper))
print('True value: %.3f' % yhat_out)
# plot dataset and prediction with interval
pyplot.scatter(x, y)
pyplot.plot(x, yhat, color='red')
pyplot.errorbar(x_in, yhat_out, yerr=interval, color='black', fmt='o')
pyplot.show()
```

When I try that, it gives me  this error.

```
     x_in = x[1001]
IndexError: index 1001 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1000
```

My goal is to predict the behavior of my data in the future and evalute it by  plotting its error bars too. I see this example [how do you create a linear regression forecast on time series data in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31147594/how-do-you-create-a-linear-regression-forecast-on-time-series-data-in-python)  but I don't understand how to apply it to my data. I found that it is possible to use ARIMA model.  Please How could  I do that?

Comment: Look at your `x` definition: if it has 1000 elements, `x[1001]` will throw an `IndexError`. You can define a larger set for `x` (say, 2000 elements), the use the first 1000 to create `y`. Also remember indices in python starts from 0 (not 1).

Comment: @Mstaino Thank you very much for your answer. But, that is my goal is to know x_in value that it is not present in my initial vector. that means  I need to estimate the future

Answer (score 0):

```
x = 20 * randn(1000) + 100
```

^ Here you are creating input vector X with only 1000 values.

```
y = x + (10 * randn(1000) + 50)
```

^ and here you creating output vector y with again only 1000 values.

So when you do `x_in = x[1001]`, you are referring to an element that is not present in the input vector as it contains only 1000 elements.

A quick fix would be

```
seed(1)
x = 20 * randn(1001) + 100
print(numpy.size(x))
y = x + (10 * randn(1001) + 50)
print(numpy.size(y))
# fit linear regression model
b1, b0, r_value, p_value, std_err = linregress(x[:1000], y[:1000])
# make predictions
yhat = b0 + b1 * x
# define new input, expected value and prediction
x_in = x[1000]
y_out = y[1000]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. That is my goal is to know  x_in value that it is not present in my  initial vector.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code for a graphing ploynomial fitter to fit a first order polynomial using numpy.polyfit() to perform the fit and mu,py.polyval() to predict values. You can experiment with different polynomial orders by changing the line "polynomialOrder = 1" at the top of the code.

```
import numpy, matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xData = numpy.array([1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.0, 6.6, 7.7, 0.0])
yData = numpy.array([1.1, 20.2, 30.3, 40.4, 50.0, 60.6, 70.7, 0.1])

polynomialOrder = 1 # example straight line

# curve fit the test data
fittedParameters = numpy.polyfit(xData, yData, polynomialOrder)
print('Fitted Parameters:', fittedParameters)

modelPredictions = numpy.polyval(fittedParameters, xData)
absError = modelPredictions - yData

SE = numpy.square(absError) # squared errors
MSE = numpy.mean(SE) # mean squared errors
RMSE = numpy.sqrt(MSE) # Root Mean Squared Error, RMSE
Rsquared = 1.0 - (numpy.var(absError) / numpy.var(yData))
print('RMSE:', RMSE)
print('R-squared:', Rsquared)

print()


##########################################################
# graphics output section
def ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)
    axes = f.add_subplot(111)

    # first the raw data as a scatter plot
    axes.plot(xData, yData,  'D')

    # create data for the fitted equation plot
    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(xData), max(xData))
    yModel = numpy.polyval(fittedParameters, xModel)

    # now the model as a line plot
    axes.plot(xModel, yModel)

    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot

graphWidth = 800
graphHeight = 600
ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight)
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help. Could you please explain for me the role of using numpy.polyfit()  to estimate the future of data ( data that is not  included in my initial vector data). Thanks in advanc.

Comment: See the line of code with "yModel = numpy.polyval(fittedParameters, xModel)" which does exactly what you ask.